# SQL invalid column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is working query;

```
@tc varchar(11),
@urun nvarchar(50),
@islem nvarchar(20),
@ilk_agirlik nvarchar(4),
@son_Agirlik nvarchar(4)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @tabloadi NVARCHAR(15)
declare @sutunadi1 nvarchar(max)
set @sutunadi1 = @urun+N'_'+@islem+N'_ilk'
declare @sutunadi2 nvarchar(max)
set @sutunadi2 = @urun+N'_'+@islem+N'_son'
SET @tabloadi=@tc
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME=@tabloadi
                AND COLUMN_NAME=@sutunadi1)
BEGIN 
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    SET @Sql = N'insert into dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@Tc)
      + N'(' + QUOTENAME(@sutunadi1)+ N',' + QUOTENAME(@sutunadi2) + N',   gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika) ' 
      + N'VALUES (' + @ilk_agirlik+ N',' + @son_agirlik + N',' + convert(varchar(2),day(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),month(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()))  + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,GETDATE())) + N')'
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql 
END
```

When i've added 2 columns which names are urun and islem to the table
i've just changed this code;

```
    SET @Sql = N'insert into dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@Tc)
      + N'(' + QUOTENAME(@sutunadi1)+ N',' + QUOTENAME(@sutunadi2) + N',   gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika, urun, islem) ' 
      + N'VALUES (' + @ilk_agirlik+ N',' + @son_agirlik + N',' + convert(varchar(2),day(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),month(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()))  + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,GETDATE())) + N',' + @urun + N',' + @islem + N')'
```

it produce an error that "invalid column name" 
what is the mistake, i've just added two columns to working query????

Comment: varchar's dates has to have quotes

Comment: Use CHAR(39) in select and use CONCAT() instead of +

Comment: Print the @SQL before executing it to see if there is something wrong with the statement.

Comment: I tried to use concat() but it didn't work and i can't understand the other solution - where should i use char(39)

Comment: i printed the @sql i think the problem is about quotes - insert into dbo.[14993458014]([Çipura_Fileto_ilk],[Çipura_Fileto_son], gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika, urun, islem) VALUES (11,2,3,4,2017,23,51,ew, eee)

Comment: how can i fix it? i think the problem is about quotes. print output is -  insert into dbo.[14993458014]([Çipura_Fileto_ilk],[Çipura_Fileto_son], gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika, urun, islem) VALUES (11,2,3,4,2017,23,51,ew, eee) - i think it should be  insert into dbo.[14993458014]([Çipura_Fileto_ilk],[Çipura_Fileto_son], gun, ay, yil, saat, dakika, urun, islem) VALUES (11,2,3,4,2017,23,51,'ew', 'eee')

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last line with:

```
+ N'VALUES (' + @ilk_agirlik+ N',' + @son_agirlik + N',' + convert(varchar(2),day(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),month(GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()))  + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,GETDATE())) + N',' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,GETDATE())) + N',''' + @urun + N''',''' +@islem + N''')'
```

Answer (score 0):

it solved. thanx  Kannan Kandasamy  for the solution when i used char(39) and concat it solved.

```
  SET @Sql = concat('insert into dbo.', QUOTENAME(@Tc),
         '(', QUOTENAME(@sutunadi1),',',QUOTENAME(@sutunadi2) ,', gun, ay,   yil, saat, dakika, urun, islem) ' 
          ,'VALUES (' , @ilk_agirlik,',' , @son_agirlik ,',',convert(varchar(2),day(GETDATE())) ,',',convert(varchar(2),month(GETDATE())) ,',' ,  convert(varchar(4),year(GETDATE()))  ,',' , convert(varchar(2),datepart(hh,GETDATE())) ,',' , convert(varchar(2),datepart(mi,GETDATE())) ,',' , char(39), @urun,char(39),',',  char(39),@islem,char(39) ,')')
```